# Math.sin() method keeps returning value of 1, not -1~1

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to create a p5.js sketch based on an image that i inspired.
https://twitter.com/dmitricherniak/status/1287101982268948483?s=20 He made it with three.js.

I wrote a code that draw an array of circles and can control the length of circles by alpha.
But when i tried to modify color change by using Math.sin() function(method) it is not working.
As I increase this.hs, the result of this.Roff = sin(this.hs) keep returns 1.
I want them to be -1 to 1 and keep returning back and force.
Also I tried lerpColor() function to shift the color(also using sin()) but still returns 1.

I also wonder anyone knows how to generate more than 2 color gradient.
I want the gradient keep looping as well.

I made following animation example in Cinema 4D.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zTrIXJPMbqOsrx6VmLNrYdDCWvfmFSQ0/view?usp=sharing

```
class Particle {
  constructor(x, y, v) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vx = -v;
    this.vy = v;
    this.alp = 50;
    
    // THIS.ROFF KEEPS RETURNING 1
    this.hs = PI / 2;
    this.inc = 0.1;
    this.Roff = sin(this.hs);
    this.Rshift = map(this.Roff, -1, 1, 0, 255);
  }

  finish() {
    return this.alp < 0;
  }
  
  update() {
    this.x += this.vx;
    this.y += this.vy;
    
    this.alp -= 2;  
    this.hs += this.inc;
  }

  display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(this.Rshift, 0, 0, this.alp);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, 200);
  }

}
```

Comment: At the time you're calling `sin(this.hs);`, `this.hs` is always `PI / 2`. You need to move the lines that set `this.Roff` and `this.Rshift` into your `update()` function. These lines do not extend into the future, they only run once for each particle.

Comment: How is it that `PI` and `sin` work(?) without preceding them with `Math.`?  
Are those p5 library "shortcuts"?